# Email Validation in client/server side JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, email-validation

I know this question will be closed because I studied many example of this but please see I think I am doing something different.

I coded my server side PHP email validation with this:

```
if (!filter_var($user_new_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errors .="Email,"; 
        $pass    = false;
             }
```

My client side email validation is:

```
function validateEmail(txtEmail){
 var a = document.getElementById(txtEmail).value;
 var filter = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+.[a-z]{1,4}$/;
   if(filter.test(a)){
    return true;
   }
   else{
    return false;
   }
```

So in my client side if I enter only username@domain (without .com), it's valid. I don't want that.

I need the same validaton in both client and serverside.
How to update my regular expression in JavaScript?

Comment: Actually, this is the same as every other _validate email in javascript_ question.

Comment: That regex will reject perfectly valid email addresses that I receive email to.

Comment: side note: at the end you can just put `return filter.test(a);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just escape the last '.' (dot) in your regex. When not escaped or inside brackets, a dot matches any character except new line. So the correct value for `filter` is:

```
var filter = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-z]{1,4}$/;
```

Answer (score 1):

@Diego has the answer you're looking for, but there are a few reasons why it really doesn't matter if you validate completely in your javascript:

1. Client-side validation can always be bypassed. You have to do the complete validation on the server side, so client-side validation is primarily a courtesy to your regular users. At most, it serves to provide fast feedback regarding form errors and saves you a few requests.
2. Validating email addresses is hard. The majority of validators (including your JavaScript example) are too strict, according to RFCs 2822 and 5322. Read [this article](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx) to get some idea of how bizarre valid addresses can be.

Answer (score 0):

use jquery validation plugin it is very easy to use and customizable 
eg.Jquery Validation Plugin and Position Absolute Jquery validation plugin